# PhP Contact form shows a blank page

Tags: php, string, html, forms, contacts

```
    <?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $to = 'email@email.com';

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . 'Regards, ' . $_POST['name'] . '.';
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email@email.com'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

When i click "SEND" on my contact form it goes to a blank page, however I do recieve the email. What's wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Carl

**Website**

http://www.vrijeme-reklame.net

**Contact form blank page**

http://www.vrijeme-reklame.net/demo-contacts.php

Error message:

> [Wed Mar 16 15:58:34.846118 2016] [lsapi:error] [pid 220778] [client 94.253.149.34:56523] mod_lsapi: [host www.vrijeme-reklame.net] [req POST /demo-contacts.php HTTP/1.1]: Could not stat script filename (/home/vrijemer/public_html/demo-contacts.php): errno 2, referer: http://www.vrijeme-reklame.net/

Comment: A blank page usually means an unreported error.  Turn on error reporting, check the logs, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @David . What could this mean?
[Wed Mar 16 15:58:34.846118 2016] [lsapi:error] [pid 220778] [client 94.253.149.34:56523] mod_lsapi: [host www.vrijeme-reklame.net] [req POST /demo-contacts.php HTTP/1.1]: Could not stat script filename (/home/vrijemer/public_html/demo-contacts.php): errno 2, referer: http://www.vrijeme-reklame.net/

Comment: This page outputs nothing. No `echo`, `print`, or content outside PHP block. After mailing a blank page I would expect.

Comment: Above code snipet is of `demo-contacts.php` ?

Comment: $_POST['email@email.com'] as you sure you have an field name="email@email.com" ?

Comment: The correct email is set. I just wrote it like this so the email doesn't get crawled from the forum. @Hirenpatel Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `demo-contact.php` does not print anything.
Try adding some `echo` statement and it will not show blank page.instead it will print those echo statement.

Other thing , you can do is , Try to redirect to some specified url whenever you want.
`header('Location: http://www.vrijeme-reklame.net/#contact');`

Comment: Thanks mate. Have to figure out to add a "Your message has been sent". But it does redirect back to contact now after clicking SEND.

Comment: do not redirect demo-contact.php and redirect back to main page. use ajax for this purpose. it will send request to demo-contact.php with out refresh/redirect. and after successfull response from ajax you can show alert ""Your message has been sent".

Answer (score 0):

Your html page redirects to this php page, which then handles your data according to the code you have written, however, php code is not displayed on the page directly, similarly to javascript. If you would like this page to display information, use echo in your php, or create html tags and put html in those. Alternatively, if you wished to not redirect to this page, and simply allow your php page to handle the code while remaining on the page with the form, google and us jquery and $.ajax

Comment: Thank you. It redirects back to the contact page, but doesn't display a "Your message has been sent" for now until I sort that.

Comment: If you are just going to redirect back to the page that sent you to the php page I would strongly recommend using ajax, then you can put your code to let people know their message has been sent in the success: callback.